# Why does each level of call stack in quicksort take O(n) time to complete?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, quicksort

I've found this explanation of quicksort online:

[image: This is the call stack given in the book]

It's written that each level of the call stack takes O(n) time to complete. However, aren't we doing less than n comparisons as we go higher up the call stack ?

Answer (score 0):

O(n) time complexity ignores constant factors. The statement is treating each split as fractional constant of the original n elements. A perfect split would be about 50% and 50%, except that Lomuto type schemes don't include the pivot element on recursive calls. So in the case where the deepest layer results in 2 elements, the constant factor for O(n) would be 2/n (since (2/n)(n) == 2).